# How to count consecutive numbers in Excel?

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I have the following problem I have a row like this:

```
1 1 1 P 1 1 1 O 1 P P 1 1
```

If there are more than 5 consecutive numbers I need to mark them with conditional formating.

Do you have any idea how it could work ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Share us what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=(IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(A1:$M1)/NOT(ISNUMBER(A1:$M1)),1),COLUMNS($A1:$M1)+1)- 
IFERROR(AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN($A1:A1)/NOT(ISNUMBER($A1:A1)),1),0))-1>5
```

[image]

Find the difference between the position of the previous non-number and the position of the next non-number.

If no previous non-number, use zero.

If no next non-number, use number of columns in range plus 1.